# All inputs in Next.js are causing a full re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I'm working on a Next.js app right now using version `12.1.5`, and I'm running into a really crazy bug. Every input component is causing a full re-render on every keystroke, leading to a loss of focus on the input. This applies to `input`, `textarea`, and even the `@monaco-editor/react` package. I had the same issue in `Formik` forms, and was weirdly able to solve the problem by switching to `react-hook-form`. But, I'm still seeing it on all of my components that accept keystrokes.

I've tried moving the component's value state up the tree, tried putting the state local to the component, and I've had absolutely no luck. This is what my `input` component looks like:

**Input.tsx**

```
import { forwardRef, InputHTMLAttributes, ReactNode, Ref } from 'react';

import * as LabelPrimitive from '@radix-ui/react-label';
import css from 'classnames';

import { Flex } from 'containers/flex/Flex';

import s from './Input.module.scss';

interface InputProps extends InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
  label?: string;
  showLabel?: boolean;
  icon?: ReactNode;
}

export const Input = forwardRef(
  (
    { showLabel, name, className, label, icon, ...rest }: InputProps,
    ref: Ref<HTMLInputElement>
  ) => {
    return (
      <Flex column className={css(s.input, className)}>
        {showLabel && (
          <LabelPrimitive.Label htmlFor={name} className={s.input__label}>
            {label}
          </LabelPrimitive.Label>
        )}
        <Flex alignCenter className={s.input__icon}>
          {icon && icon}
        </Flex>
        <input
          ref={ref}
          name={name}
          {...rest}
          className={css(s.input__field, icon && s.hasIcon)}
        />
      </Flex>
    );
  }
);

Input.displayName = 'Input';
```

If I implement a value like this:

**TestComponent.tsx**

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Input } from 'elements/input/Input';

export const TestComponent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  return <Input value={value} onChange={setValue}/>;
};
```

Any time I try to type I lose focus. Again, this has happened on every implementation of inputs that I've tried outside of `react-hook-form`, and includes the `@monaco-editor/react` package.

Here, also, is my package.json in case I've got any issues with other packages.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.6.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "vercel:build": "prisma generate && prisma migrate deploy && next build",
    "dev:connect": "pscale connect veroskills development --port 3309",
    "shadow:connect": "pscale connect veroskills shadow --port 3309",
    "slicemachine": "start-slicemachine",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.8.8",
    "@monaco-editor/react": "^4.4.4",
    "@next-auth/prisma-adapter": "^1.0.3",
    "@prisma/client": "^3.13.0",
    "@prismicio/client": "^6.4.2",
    "@prismicio/helpers": "^2.2.1",
    "@prismicio/next": "^0.1.2",
    "@prismicio/react": "^2.2.0",
    "@prismicio/slice-simulator-react": "^0.2.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-alert-dialog": "^0.1.7",
    "@radix-ui/react-checkbox": "^0.1.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^0.1.7",
    "@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu": "^0.1.6",
    "@radix-ui/react-icons": "^1.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-label": "^0.1.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-progress": "^0.1.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-scroll-area": "^0.1.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-select": "^0.1.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-separator": "^0.1.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-switch": "^0.1.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-tabs": "^0.1.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-toast": "^0.1.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-toolbar": "^0.1.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-tooltip": "^0.1.7",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.0",
    "next": "^12.1.5",
    "next-auth": "^4.3.1",
    "next-compose-plugins": "^2.2.1",
    "next-images": "^1.8.4",
    "next-react-svg": "^1.1.3",
    "node-mocks-http": "^1.11.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "plyr-react": "^3.2.1",
    "prismic-reactjs": "^1.3.4",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-code-blocks": "^0.0.9-0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-gravatar": "^2.6.3",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.30.0",
    "react-loading-skeleton": "^3.1.0",
    "react-select": "^5.2.2",
    "react-table": "^7.7.0",
    "react-use-keypress": "^1.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.50.0",
    "swr": "^1.3.0",
    "use-monaco": "^0.0.40",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@prismicio/types": "^0.1.27",
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "@types/node": "17.0.21",
    "@types/react": "18.0.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-gravatar": "^2.6.10",
    "@types/react-table": "^7.7.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.18.0",
    "eslint": "8.12.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "lint-staged": "^12.3.7",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "prisma": "^3.13.0",
    "slice-machine-ui": "^0.3.7",
    "ts-jest": "^27.1.4",
    "turbo": "^1.2.4",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": [
      "yarn eslint --fix",
      "yarn prettier --write"
    ]
  }
}
```

I am completely at a loss here; does anyone have idea what the issue could be?

Comment: When I hear the description of issue like this I typically think to look if *some* React component has been declared within another React component. Can you provide a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: I can try; I haven’t been able to replicate it when I’ve been working with packages in codesandbox, but I’ll give it a look.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a component being declared in another component? Is this something that could be caused by a React context? I removed the input component and just used a plain old text input and the issue is the same.

Comment: No, it's when you've a component, and inside that component you declare another component. Something like `const Outer = () => { ... const Inner = () => "Inner"; ... return ( ... <Inner /> ... ); }`. The issue here is that `Inner` is redeclared each render cycle, the old is unmounted, the new mounted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out my problem through some extensive debugging. I have a reusable `Flex` component that utilizes `createElement` to allow me to create a flex box of any element by passing in an element type- `div`, `button`, `nav` etc, and I use that component within my input component. Getting rid of my `createElement` function and replacing it with a simple `div` fixed the problem, so now I just need to refactor the `Flex` component to still allow for any element type.

All that to say, the `Flex` component was causing a full render whenever it's children changed. Off to correct.